# Los archivos PHP se descargan en lugar de ejecutarse con php8.1-fpm nginx Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php8

Se que hay muchísima información, la he buscado y he pasado toda la noche haciendo pruebas sin exito.
He instalado todo con este comando:
`sudo apt install php8.1 php8.1-fpm php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring php8.1-xml php8.1-curl`

En `/etc/nginx/sites-available` tengo el archivo `default` y `mi.sitio.com`

**Contenido de `default`:**

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

**Contenido de `mi.sitio.com`:**

```
server {
        root /var/www/mi.sitio.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

        server_name mi.sitio.com www.mi.sitio.com;

    #Anterior funcionando nginx antes de PHP
    #location / {
         #       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        
       # }
        
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mi.sitio.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mi.sitio.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.mi.sitio.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mi.sitio.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name mi.sitio.com www.mi.sitio.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

**Versión de Ubuntu:**  `lsb_release -a`

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

**Versión de PHP:**  `php -v`

```
PHP 8.1.22 (cli) (built: Aug 14 2023 05:32:33) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.22, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

**Versión de PHP:**  `mysql`
Server version: 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 (Ubuntu)

**Versión de PHP:**  `nginx -v`

```
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Cualquier otro dato que necesiten me lo hacen saber y por adelantado les doy las gracias por su tiempo y la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: creoque tu pregunta seria mejor recibida en https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2):

El comportamiento por defecto de nginx es servir todo lo que está en el document root (o sea en `/var/www/mi.sitio.com/html`)

Para que los archivos php se ejecuten como tal tienes que pasárselos a `php-fpm`

```
server {

    # server_name, index, etc

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

El valor de `fastcgi_pass` puede variar para tu caso. Por ejemplo podrías tener php-fpm escuchando en un puerto en vez de un sock

Para habilitar las url bonitas lo que se hace es decirle a nginx: cuando se pida una url:

```
 - si el archivo existe, sírvelo 
 - si es hay una carpeta con ese nombre, sirve el index dentro de esa parpera
 - si no existe, pásale el request a `index.php` en el document root
```

Y eso se hace con el bloque

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Ahora, por qué si los archivos php existen, no se sirven como texto (que es lo que quieres evitar)?

Es porque la regla que puse al principio tiene prioridad sobre la primera, y no por una cuestión de orden sino de especificidad.

```
    location ~ \.php$
```

Usa una expresión regular y tiene máxima prioridad

```
    location /
```

Es genérica y tiene mínima prioridad

Si tuvieras un bloque

```
    location /api/
```

Este tendría más prioridad que `/` pero menos que  `~ \.php$`

Redondeando, tu bloque `server` quedaría

```
server {
    root /var/www/mi.sitio.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name mi.sitio.com www.mi.sitio.com;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mi.sitio.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mi.sitio.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: odio nginx pero es necesario XD

Comment: y qué preferirías? lighttpd ?

Comment: es que no me gusta la configuracion de nginx ...

Comment: @ffflabs gracias por tu tiempo y respuesta, recién llego del trabajo y he probado el código. Ahora no me descarga los archivos PHP como sucedía antes, pero en su lugar me muestra una página en blanco.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado luego de horas de batallar, debo decir que además del código le aumenté 1GB de RAM al servidor que estaba funcionando en una instancia aws t2.micro con solo 1GB RAM, no se si tiene que ver, pero una pequeá modificación del código hizo el milagro.

Dejé el archivo default como está arriba, solo modifiqué el del sitio que está ubicado en **/etc/nginx/sites-available**

```
server {
        root /var/www/mi.sitio.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

        server_name mi.sitio.com www.mi.sitio.com;
 
    location / {
                      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
         }

         location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mi.sitio.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mi.sitio.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Agradecer nuevamente a @ffflabs por su amabilidad y por la enseñanza que me brindó al compartir sus ideas.

Comment: Cómo dije, lo que hay dentro del bloque php puede varias. Me alegro que hayas podido dar con la solución. No creo por qué eso si tú usted que aumentar la ram. Yo he servido sitios medianos con una t3.nano